# Problem with renewcommand?

Tags: macros

I want to change the command `\textsubscript` to `\tsub` by writing the following line in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\textsubscript}{\tsub}
```

but, unfortunately, it doesn't work !

Comment: Did you try `\let`? You wrote `\renewcomman` instead of `\renewcommand`.

Comment: Does `\tsub` previously defined?

Comment: The other way around: `\newcommand{\tsub}{\textsubscript}`

Comment: @ Marco Daniel ... I wrote it \renewcommand in my document. I tried \let and it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following instead of \renewcommand:

```
\let\tsub\textsubscript
```

Comment: @ DL6ER ... It works ! , Thank you :)

Comment: But what is the problem with using '\renewcommand'

Comment: Typing: `\renewcommand{\textsubscript}{\tsub}` does the following: Take whatever `\textsubscript` does and throw it away. Let then `\tsub` be executed when `\textsubscript` is called. But `\tsub` might not be defined, so LaTeX don't know what to do and stop.

Comment: It's always good to know why something fails ;-) You might mark the answer as "accepted", so others will see, that this question is solved, when they have a similar problem and look for a solution.