# Xelatex renewcommand

Tags: xetex

I am trying to renew \overline into \bar in a Xelatex document but Xelatex does not compile and I do not understand why I get the error "\bar is already defined".

Here is my Xelatex code :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\renewcommand{\bar}{\overline}

\begin{document}
$\bar{ABCD}$\\
$\overline{ABCD}$
\end{document}
```

But when I am in normal Latex mode, this code compiles perfectly :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\bar}{\overline}

\begin{document}
$\bar{ABCD}$\\
$\overline{ABCD}$
\end{document}
```

I have been searching a related topic but so far, I have not found any solution.

( The answer here : [Problem with renewcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106359/problem-with-renewcommand) did not work for bar )

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try `\let\bar\overline` instead or `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bar}{\overline}}` but I doubt the usefulness of the idea at all

Comment: The problem is that fontspec (loaded by polyglossia) tries to declare the \bar accent at \begin{document}. You must do your redefinition later, or use another name.

Comment: The first option does not work either, I have already tried it. But the second one is working, thank you very much ! :)

Comment: @AdrienMeilac: Yes, forget the first option. It would work if used in `\AtBeginDocument{...}` however.

Comment: + Ulrike Fische : Ok , Are there other commands like bar that I could not renew with polyglossia ?

Answer (score 3):

Quite interesting!

What happens is that `fontspec` (which is loaded by `polyglossia`) has to redefine `\bar` using a different math symbol font than in standard LaTeX, so it call (at begin document)

```
\DeclareMathAccent{\bar}{\mathalpha}{legacymaths}{22}
```

The working of `\DeclareMathAccent` is complex, but in essence it checks whether its first argument (here `\bar`) is either undefined or defined as a math accent; in this case it (re)defines it as requested. If the command is already defined not to be a math accent, it raises an error.

Since you're doing `\renewcommand{\bar}{\overline}`, we are in the second situation, because `\overline` is not a math accent (from TeX’s point of view).

Solution:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bar}{\overline}}
```

which will do the redefinition later than the one performed by `fontspec`. This will also work in standard LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you think like Ulrike Fische that I should not use \bar and choose another name or other errors could appear in the document because of that renewcommand ?

Comment: @AdrienMeilac In my opinion, `\overline` is no substitute for `\bar`. It's a necessary evil in case you have to overline several letters, but I usually prefer the shorter `\bar`. You can look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357922/ for importing `\widebar` from `mathabx` (but it doesn't stretch to cover four letters).