# Fontspec redefines Siunitx symbols

Tags: symbols, fontspec, siunitx, polyglossia

I'm trying to find a solution to an already described problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365376/xelatex-renewcommand). The `\Omega` symbol does not display when loading `fontspec` (in this case implicitly from the package `polyglossia`). I've found this problem but I'm sure it will affect other symbols.

I think page 58 from the `siunitx` [manual](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) dedicates some words to this, but I don't know how to interpret/fix the problem. Here is a sample:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% Language of the document
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}

%% Units
\usepackage{siunitx}

%% Change document's fonts
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
    $ R=50\si{\ohm} $\par % Does not work
    $ R=50\Omega $        % Works
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `T1` font encoding that `mathdesign` package applies to the document does not like to be with XeLaTeX, so better use an OpenType font with math support like `stix2`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% Math and text fonts
\usepackage{stix2}

%% Units
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    $ R=50\si{\ohm} $\par % Works
    $ R=50\Omega $        % Works
\end{document}
```